# Can I dispatch Fibers over a threadPool in D

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, d, fiber, vibed

What I want is to gain the Fiber's high efficiency on context switching and yield CPU time during I/O, but when the workload is enough to feed more CPUs I would like to gain the performance from the fact of do things in parallel.

I read this great article about Threads and Fibers
https://octarineparrot.com/article/view/getting-more-fiber-in-your-diet

And read this question regarding of comparison between fibers and threads.
[Fibers over Threads in D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481498/fibers-over-threads-in-d)

But I want to get any light about a good way to mix them agnostic and gracefully.
Of course, code samples are welcome.

Comment: What exactly is your question? "How to mix fibers and threads" is not a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You can.

Quote from the documentation:

> Please note that there is no requirement that a fiber be bound to one specific thread. Rather, fibers may be freely passed between threads so long as they are not currently executing.

Obviously you can use pool of threads to run your fibers.

Comment: IIRC this is broken on most compilers.

Comment: I am pretty sure that "are no currently executing" means "are terminated", not "are suspended". That should work afaik.